# Cucumber inconsistent behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, capybara

I am trying to run test features."bundle exec cucumber features" starts failing abnormally(during login itself),it fails to recognize an existing user. while it works fine if i run individual feature files. What am i doing wrong?

Gem File:

```
group :test do
  gem 'ruby-prof'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'selenium-client'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'email_spec', :branch=>'rails3'
end
```

In env.rb

```
begin
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
rescue NameError
  raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
end
```

Comment: you'll need to provide some more information - what sort of failures you're getting, and the code that causes them.

Comment: as i said,its sometimes failing during signing in a user,sometimes it passes for different features.Its perfectly working if i bundle exec individual files.My guess is database is getting truncated after i run a scenario,so it doesn't get a registered user.

Comment: Yes, the database cleaner strategy :transaction will roll back your database after each test. That's what it's designed to do.